# CoreData, getting an element of my in my object coredata

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

i would like to get the names of my element predicted. could you please help me

this is my code :

```
NSNumber *min = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:30];
NSNumber *max = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:100];
NSPredicate *predi;
predi = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"number BETWEEN %@", [NSArray arrayWithObjects:min, max, nil]];

NSArray  *BoxWithPriceBetween = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predi]; 

NSLog(@"Box %@", BoxWithPriceBetween);
```

this is my result :

```
2012-05-02 17:42:28.019 CoreDataTuto[2690:fb03] Box (
    "<Phone: 0xba68790> (entity: Phone; id: 0xba687c0 <x-coredata:///Phone/t73E15BA0-90CA-4AEA-91B4-93BD8FD328737> ; data: {\n    name = NAME6;\n    number = 40;\n})",
    "<Phone: 0xba64dc0> (entity: Phone; id: 0xba64df0 <x-coredata:///Phone/t73E15BA0-90CA-4AEA-91B4-93BD8FD328735> ; data: {\n    name = NAME4;\n    number = 33;\n})",
    "<Phone: 0xba572a0> (entity: Phone; id: 0xba571e0 <x-coredata:///Phone/t73E15BA0-90CA-4AEA-91B4-93BD8FD328733> ; data: {\n    name = NAME2;\n    number = 33;\n})",
    "<Phone: 0xba64d20> (entity: Phone; id: 0xba64d50 <x-coredata:///Phone/t73E15BA0-90CA-4AEA-91B4-93BD8FD328734> ; data: {\n    name = NAME3;\n    number = 43;\n})"
)
```

and i want to get all of the names predicted.

thanks !

Comment: please explain what you want a bit more clearly - not sure what you're driving at

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but if you want to get the name attribute from each object, then try something like this...

```
for (NSManagedObject *object in BoxWithPriceBetween) {
    NSString *name = [object valueForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way

```
NSArray *names = [BoxWithPriceBetween valueForKey:@"name"];
```

From the [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) docs

> **valueForKey:**
> Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects.

---

### Side note

variables are conventionally named starting with a lowercase letter and then camel cased from then on. e.g. `BoxWithPriceBetween` should be `boxWithPriceBetween`